# Solve second order differential equation of resonance.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **Solve equation** 
>   $$ y'' + y = \sin x $$

$$y=e^{rx}$$

$$r^2e^{rx}+e^{rx}=0$$

$$r^2 +1 =0$$

$$r=-i, \ r =i \tag{1}$$

I use the equation 
$$y=y_0 + A e^{\alpha x} \cos\beta x + Be^{\alpha x} \sin\beta x$$

where from $(1)$: $\alpha = 0 ,\ \beta = 1 $ or  $\alpha = 0 ,\ \beta = -1 $

I get 
$$y = A \cos x + B \sin x $$ $$y = A \cos x - B \sin x$$

because $A,\ B$ are real constants the only solution is:

$$ y = y_0 + A \cos x + B \sin x ,\  A,B \in \mathbb{R} $$

$$ y_0 = u_1(x) \cos x + u_2(x) \sin x $$

$$ y_0' = u_1'\cos x -u_1\sin x + u_2' \sin x + u_2 \cos x \tag{2} $$

**There is assumption which I don't understand:**

$$ u_1' \cos x + u_2'\sin x =0 $$

and with this assumption from $(2)$

$$ y_0'= -u_1\sin x + u_2\cos x $$

$$y_0'' = -u_1'\sin x -u_1\cos x + u_2'\cos x -u_2\sin x $$

And then we have two equations which we have to solve:

$$ u_1'\cos x +u_2'\sin x = 0 $$

$$ -u_1'\sin x +u_2'\cos x = \sin x $$

...

Comment: This extra assumption is not essential, it is made for ease of computing the solution. Look up variation of parameters.

Comment: Use `\sin x` and `\cos x` for trig functions instead of `sinx` and `cosx`

Comment: $u_1'' - u_1 + 2u_2' +u_1' +u_2 =0$ and $-u_1'+u_2'' -u_2 -u_1 =1$

Comment: That is what I get without this assumption... I have no idea what to do with it :)

Comment: @grzegorzs My point is that just writing down variation of parameters and substituting it into the ODE gives you two unknown functions and only one ODE. So you need some additional condition to uniquely specify the variation of parameters solution. Alternatively, you can just plug it in and make an additional assumption "on the fly" to choose your solution, instead of using a rule that happens to be convenient in many problems (but can be hard to remember).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y''+y=\sin(x)$$
This is a second order linear non-homogeneous ODE.

First, solve the associated second order linear homogeneous ODE :
$$Y''+Y=0 \quad\to\quad Y=A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)$$
$A$ and $B$ are constants.

Second, find a solution of the non-homogeneous ODE thanks to the variation of parameters method (for example). That is, remplace the constants by functions :
$$y_0(x)=f(x)\cos(x)+g(x)\sin(x)$$
Note that we don't need to solve for the general solution $y(x)$ but only for any one solution $y_0(x)$
A short way should be to guess a simple form for the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, linear in the present case. Supposing that we cannot guess, then :

$y_0'=(f'+g)\cos(x)+(g'-f)\sin(x)$

$y_0''=(f''+2g'-f)\cos(x)+(g''-2f'-g)\sin(x)$

$y_0''+y_0=\sin(x)=(f''+2g'-f)\cos(x)+(g''-2f'-g)\sin(x)+f\cos(x)+g\sin(x)$

$(f''+2g')\cos(x)+(g''-2f')\sin(x)=\sin(x)\quad\to\quad 
\begin{cases}f''+2g'=0\\g''-2f'=1\end{cases}$

Of course, we could continue and use a sledgehammer to crack a nut! But since we don't need all solutions, but only one, obviously $\quad f=-\frac{x}{2}\quad $ and $\quad g=0\quad$ is sufficient.
$$y_0(x)=-\frac{x}{2}\cos(x)$$
The general solution of $y''+y=\sin(x)$ is : $\quad y(x)=y_0(x)+Y(x)$
$$y(x)=-\frac{x}{2}\cos(x)+A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)$$